# Swift Generic ViewModifier

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to create a generic view modifier I can use for rapid prototyping.

```
struct If : ViewModifier {
    var test: Bool
    var then: (_: Content) -> Content
    @ViewBuilder func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if test {
            then(content)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

What's the proper incantation to apply it to an element in the view?

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    var isActive: Bool
    HStack {}.modifier(If(test: isActive, then: ??? ))
}
```

My goal here is to be able to chain function calls conditionally on HStack and other items (e.g. `.frame()`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is difficult—probably impossible—to write this as a type conforming to `ViewModifier`. You give this type for `then`:

```
var then: (_: Content) -> Content
```

However, you're usually going to want `then` to return a different type than it was given, because that's how modifiers generally work. For example, `Text("hello")` has type `Text`, but `Text("hello").background(Color.red)` has type `ModifiedContent<Text, _BackgroundStyleModifier<Color>>`.

We can try making the modifier generic over the type returned by `then`:

```
struct If<Then: View>: ViewModifier {
    var test: Bool

    @ViewBuilder
    var then: (_: Content) -> Then

    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if test {
            then(content)
        } else {
            content
        }
    }
}
```

But then we run into a problem when we try to use the modifier:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    var isActive: Bool
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
        }.modifier(If(test: isActive, then: { $0.background(.red) }))
                // ^  Generic parameter 'Then' could not be inferred
    }
}
```

Why can't it infer the type? The type would be `ModifiedContent<Content, _BackgroundStyleModifier<Color>>`. But `Content` is actually a type alias for `_ViewModifier_Content<If>`… except that we made `If` generic over `Then`, so `Content` is a type alias for `_ViewModifier_Content<If<ModifiedContent<Content, _BackgroundStyleModifier<Color>>>>`. Oops, we just put `Content` back in there. The `Content` type alias and the `Then` type are mutually recursive, and Swift cannot handle an infinitely-nested generic type.

It is, however, possible to achieve a similar effect by extending `View` with a modifier method. You can find lots of web pages with examples by searching for “swiftui conditional modifier”. It typically looks like this:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func `if`<Content: View>(
        _ condition: Bool,
        @ViewBuilder transform: (Self) -> Content
    ) -> some View {
        if (condition) {
            transform(self)
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

and you use it like this:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    var isActive: Bool
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
        }.if(isActive) { $0.background(.red) }
    }
}
```

Note, however, that a modifier like this can cause animations and transitions to misbehave. The problem is that SwiftUI generally considers `transform(self)` and `self` to have different identities because they're in separate branches of the `if` statement. This affects how SwiftUI animates them. This may or may not be a problem for you, but it is why the general advice from Apple is to use “inert” forms of modifiers directly, instead of introducing an `if`-style modifier. That is, Apple would recommend this instead, for the example above:

```
struct ExampleView: View {
    var isActive: Bool
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
        }.background(isActive ? .red : .clear)
    }
}
```

Here, there's no `if` statement, so SwiftUI will recognize the `HStack` as being the same across changes to `isActive`, for animation purposes.

Comment: Bless you sir, I actually tried extending View in my first implementation, but I wasn't sure exactly how to set up the generics!

Comment: My aim is to conditionally add a series of chained calls (e.g. .frame().background()) without copying a ton of code when prototyping. Did not know I'd still be able to blow up other things however...